# Как посмотреть сохраненный пароль в Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, пароль

Забыл пароль от своего Google-аккаунта. Вход в Gmail и YouTube выполняется автоматически (пароль в браузере сохранён), однако сам пароль не отображается.

Вот мой вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь просмотреть пароль, если Google Chrome его сохранил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просмотреть сохранённый пароль в Google Chrome очень просто:

Заходите в настройки => Пароли